# EXCEL: How to find a cell value in column and copy the found value in another cell

Tags: excel

I need to know how can i find a value of A1 in C:C and copy the value of found cell into B1.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Will column `C` always be of the format `File=abc`, or might it have another format?

Comment: Yes Column C will be the same. Starting with File=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this in B1:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A2,MID(C:C,4,LEN(A2)),0))
```

Enter this formula with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`, since this is an array formula.
and drag down.

Comment: Still No Luck :(   #N/A

Comment: have you entered it as an array formula? instead of hitting enter, to enter the formula, press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`!

Comment: Yes i used it with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

Comment: I works fine for the example you gave us. Can you maybe give some more information on the data you have stored? maybe screenshot a small amount of the original data?

Comment: Sure i can share the exact data with you, Please provide me your email address so i can share the Excel file.

Comment: It should suffice, when you make a screenshot and update your question!

Comment: I have updated the post with another screenshot. Please check.

Comment: Saw it, give me a minute.

Comment: Ok. Try the new formula

Comment: Yeah i am getting the result, But the Only Name is coming, I need to copy the complete cell of result of Column C.

Comment: What i have check that you are copying the Cell A Value and paste it on Cell B after Matching in Cell C. But i need the value of match from Cell C to be copied and paste on Cell B.

Comment: @Faraz Hussain Try again :D

Comment: Perfect :D Thanks for your support.. Really Appreciated.

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer when it works? (Green check next to the answer)

Comment: Done (Y), Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try setting B1 to:

```
=INDEX(C:C, MATCH("File=" & A1, C:C, 0))
```

You could also use the `VLOOKUP()` function.

Comment: No results, #N/A, I have hundreds of the names with File=***, so i want to find the value of Cell A* in Column C and the result of the found cell in Cell B*

Answer (score 0):

Use VLookup

```
=VLOOKUP("File="&A1,C$1:C$4,1,FALSE)
```